# lsblk showing "P" as disk capacity which is wrong

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

As mentioned in the title, `lsblk` has "P" in couple of my disk when clearly I don't have any disk that has petabyte of capacity.
Or could the "P" here mean something completely different?

```
sdc           8:32   0 115.5P  0 disk 
├─sdc1        8:33   0  12.7T  0 part 
└─sdc9        8:41   0     8M  0 part 
sdd           8:48   0 115.5P  0 disk 
├─sdd1        8:49   0  12.7T  0 part
```

[image: Pictorial Proof showing that lsblk is showing "P" suffix in drives]

For context, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and these are `ZFS` drives.

Comment: What happens if you do `lsblk -b` to show capacity in bytes?

Comment: How's your backup procedures?

Comment: For `lsblk -b`, I get `129986248068418560` which seems to about 115 Pebibits which matches what I'm seeing. In terms of backup procedures, I use [restic](https://restic.net/) that backs up on external disk. FWIW, my setup consists of 14TB + 8TB mirrored so I have some form of redundancy still. And I just checked my zpool status and see that one of the disk seems to be degraded. Perhaps, that's what causing this to have this weird unit.

Comment: Check with /proc/partitions. If main drive shows that number, it suggests the kernel is receiving that data from the drive, and can't help but show what it's been told. The partitions however were made on the drive, so they would show the real size. Data reported by hardware can be and often is wrong or misleading, but the kernel doesn't correct it in most cases. You can also check this in /sys/block/sdc/size but it will show the same thing. You'd be amazed at how much bad data hardware reports to the kernel, it's quite random. If those sources are right, then it's a bug with lsblk.

Comment: May be problems with partition table? What output for
```
fdisk -l
```
???

Comment: @Lizardx thanks for the info. I'll make sure to do that if it happens again but I went ahead and reformatted the hard-disk. Luckily, I had backups.

Comment: I ran into a somewhat similar situation (very wrong disk size reported by lsblk), see [here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/15932). and it is also related to zfs. However, in my case I see `2TB` where it should be `7.3TB`. I guess you should consider yourself lucky, because over-estimation is probably no breaking things by itself.